# How to declare and use global variables in Django (with Eclipse)

Tags: django, eclipse, global-variables, unused-variables

I'm developing an application that needs a global variable. Fortunately, it is working despite Eclipse complaining about the way I used the global variable. To use as an example in this question, I created an application (which works!) that uses a global variable as a page counter. Here is the code:

[image]

My __init__.py file:

```
counter = 0
```

My views.py

```
from AccessCounter import counter
from django.shortcuts import render

def conterf(request):
    global counter
    counter +=1
    context = {
        'counter' : counter,
    }
    return render(request, 'AccessCounter/index.html', context)
```

And Eclipse is complaining that I have a "Unsed import: counter" at line "from AccessCounter import counter", but if I remove this line, the counter does not work with this error:

```
name 'counter' is not defined
```

I don't think that the following information is relevant, but here they are...

My index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Access counter: {{ counter }}
</body>
</html>
```

and my url.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from AccessCounter import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.conterf, name='counter'),
]
```

Comment: You can ignore what Eclipse says, but **you still shouldn't do this anyway**. It won't work as soon as you deploy your app properly. To keep data between requests you must store it somewhere, such as the database.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks for your comment. Should I consider it a bug of the eclipse? But, in the 2nd part of your comment, you told me not to use this approach, and I would appreciate it if you expand your comment. Is this approach not a good practice even if this is used, for example, for a Message-Of-The-Day?